# Postgres Driver Gradle Project

Tags: postgresql, gradle, driver

I am working on a project with database connection. It's a gradle project. in the build.gradle, I referenced PostgreSQL.
In the tab database in intellij I have added the database and the connection is successful. Everything works fine in my junit tests. But if I start the application and it tries to use the successfully tested class then I get the exception that no suitable driver was found.
build.gradle runs through without errors. the libraries are there too. And as I said the test is running error-free. The class itself somehow not.
Can someone help me please?

the build.gradle reference

```
compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.0-801.jdbc4'
```

the Connection string

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBNAME
```

but as i said - the test runs well with this configuration

Comment: Well, how do you run your application? Have you added the driver to the runtime classpath, i.e. java -cp yourjar.jar:portgresql.jar your.MainClass? gradle is a build tool. It is irrelevant when running your app.

Comment: ahh - thanx alot, this was the Problem, now it works fine